# How can I take the complex logarithm of this equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, riemann-surfaces

I have
$$
e^{i\beta}=\pm\frac{g_1}{\sqrt{1-g_0^2}}
$$
where $g_0$ is a real value and $g_1$ is complex. I'm trying to solve for $\beta$ in the equation, but I'm not quite sure how I can do that. I tried to take the logarithm so that
$$
\beta =-i \ln \left(\pm\frac{g_1}{\sqrt{1-g_0^2}}\right)
$$
However, the answer looks like
$$
\beta'=-i\log\frac{g_1}{\sqrt{1-g_0^2}}+k\pi,\ \text{where}\ k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
I'm wondering where does the $\pm$ sign go? Why there's a $+k\pi$ term? Is that relevant to the Riemann surface? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $e^{i \theta} = e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)}$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, when you solve an equation such as
$$
e^{i \theta} = w
$$
for $\theta \in \mathbb{C}$, you get one value for each integer. (The complex logarithm is *multivalued*.) However, in your equation, since you have the $\pm$ sign, you get *twice* as many solutions! To wit,
$$
e^{i(\theta + (2k+1)\pi)} = e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi) + i\pi} 
= e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)} e^{i\pi} = -e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)}.
$$

Therefore, when you're solving an equation such as $e^{i\theta} = \pm w$, you get both the even and odd multiples of $\pi$, i.e. all the integer multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! $\theta$ should be real, right?

Comment: $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $e^{i\theta}$ is on the unit circle $|z| = 1$.

Comment: More generally, say $z = \alpha + \beta i$, we have $e^z = e^{\alpha + \beta i} = e^{\alpha} e^{\beta i} = e^{\alpha}(\cos \beta + i \sin \beta)$, a point with polar coordinates $(r, \theta) = (e^{\alpha}, \theta)$.